# If we are using `identity` ID Generator and still we set the primary key to the entity object then which primary key will be stored in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, auto-increment, id-generation

> As we know if we use `identity` ID Generator in Hibernate and if we dont set the primary key value to the entity object then database will insert the primary key value.
>
> But If we are using `identity` ID Generator and still we set the primary key value to the entity class object like `entityClassObject.setPrimaryKeyNo(10)` then which primary key will be stored in the database?

1. Database Provided Primary key
2. Ours provided primary key

> Can someone prove it ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Would have taken you 10 seconds to try in your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Database provided primary key**. More accurately, primary key provided by the persistence provider.

From javadoc of [`GenerationType.IDENTITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#IDENTITY):

> **IDENTITY**
>
> `public static final GenerationType IDENTITY`
>
> Indicates that the persistence provider ***must*** assign primary keys for the entity using a ***database identity column***.

From [**Hibernate-5.3.1.Final** User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity):

> **2.6.9. Using IDENTITY columns**
>
> For implementing identifier value generation based on `IDENTITY`
>   columns, Hibernate makes use of its `org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator`
>   id generator which expects the identifier to generated **by INSERT into
>   the table**.